# C++ How to only accept a char input and make the program exit if user inputs string or int etc

Tags: c++, input

Hey guys so I'm writing a program where I can only in one letter(ex. a,b,c) and I want the program to exit if the user tries to enter anything else ex)string int etc. The code sample I have so far is this. When I try to run this it the program will always say that the input is a letter.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){

    char guess;
    bool isnotletter
    cout<<"Enter your guess"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;

    isnotletter=cin.fail();//cin.fail returns true if the input is something that disagrees with the data type (ex string and int would)


    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    if(isnotletter==true)
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    else
       cout<<"You are a letter"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: For one, "character" and "letter" are two very different things. `cin>>guess;` knows nothing about letters. Perhaps you want to research `std::isalpha`. Maybe also `getline` if you want to see that the user has entered more than one character in a line.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this, including flushing the line in case of bad input, would be to read the whole line and see if it consisted of a single character:

```
std::string s;

if ( !getline( cin, s ) )    // reads a whole line
    cout << "Error or end-of-file\n";

else if ( s.size() != 1 )
    cout << "Input was not a single character\n";

else if ( !isalpha(s[0], locale()) )
    cout << "Input was not a letter\n";

else
    cout<<"You are a letter"<<endl;
```

Of course, you could combine some of those error conditions if you are not interested in specific error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think `isalpha()` function helps you.
[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main(){

    string guess;
    cout<<"Enter your guess"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;

    if( (!isalpha(guess[0])) || (guess.size() > 1) )
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    else
        cout<<"You are a letter"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It still takes in the string as valid which I don't want. I only the input to be valid if they only put one letter.

Comment: Don't forget to account for `(guess.size() == 0)` before accessing `guess[0]`

Comment: could you illuminate me why I should account for it ? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname: in case `cin >> guess` fails and returns a blank string. Accessing `guess[0]` on a blank string would be an error. A safer statement would be `if( (guess.size() != 1) || (!isalpha(guess[0])) )`.

Comment: I understand thank you for the idea.But up to now, I've never succeed to insert blank string. @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0):

`cin.fail()` will return true if there is an exception thrown when assigning a value, that much is correct. However, using `cin` to receive a string and assign it to a character doesn't throw an exception, as what happens is that `cin` simply takes the first character in the input buffer and assigns it to `guess`, leaving the rest of the string in queue within the input buffer. This is considered acceptable by `cin`.

In your code, if the user had written "hello", `guess`will have the character `h`. If you use another `cin` below, and assign it to let's say `char mychar`, it won't ask the user again, as there is still input waiting. Instead, it'll assign the next character `e` to `mychar`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main(){

    char guess;
    char mychar;
    bool isnotletter;
    cout<<"Enter your guess"<<endl;
    cin>>guess;

    isnotletter=cin.fail();
    //cin.fail returns true if the input is something that disagrees with the data type (ex string and int would)

    cin>>mychar;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    if(isnotletter==true)
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    else
       cout<<"You are a letter"<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The second char `mychar` will receive the second character in the first string input, without asking for the user to input again.

A solution could be using a `string` to get all the inputs, and if you want then you can assign the first letter of the string to your `char`. Later, you can use `if` and measure the string size, and if it is >1 then output the Error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string myString;
    char mychar;

    cout<<"Enter your guess"<<endl;

    cin >> myString;
    mychar = myString[0];

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    if(myString.size() > 1)
    {
        cout<<"Error"<<endl;
        //exit(1);
    }
    //Code to check for numbers
    else if(string::npos != myString.find_first_of("0123456789"))
    {
        cout << "digit(s)found!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
       cout<<"You are a letter"<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So how should I fix my issue so that I can only take one char as an input and if the user tries to put a number or string then it exits the program saying error?

Comment: @user5001170 Posted solution

Comment: if I input a number it says its a letter which we know isnt true

Comment: @user5001170 do you want to check if the first character is an `int` or check if there is an `int` in the whole `string`? the second method works even if you input 1-digit number

Answer (score 0):

For text validation, regex is quiet of a powerful tool in general (can be slow though).

```
regex charRegex("(\\+|-)?[[:alpha:]]+");

string input;
cout<<"Input : "<<endl;
cin>>input;

if(!regex_match(input,charRegex))
    cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
```

[Companion](http://cpprocks.com/files/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf) of every regex fanatic.